# Point domain to IP address on Cobalt Strike

Tags: domain

On Cobalt Strike how do I point a domain (in this case a subdomain) to the IP address to create a listener?

Comment: This is a networking question and not a security question, regardless of you using a security tool.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you have a listener running on your cobalt strike server and want your payload to connect to it via a domain name? In that case you need to modify your DNS record to point to the IP address. Go to your domain name registrar (where you bought the domain) and add an "A" record which ties your subdomain to that IP address. If you Google it your registrar will almost certainly have instructions on how to do it.

Comment: by the wa, I have google but haven't managed to found it. Do you know tell me how do I do it on byethost? Thanks

Comment: @little_stacker did you buy your domain on byet host or did you buy it somewhere else and are just hosting on byet host?